# Track Sql server Updation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to track the ip address of request which update table in sql server 2000/05?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in function to directly get the IP address. You can select the client hostname like this:

```
select host_name()  /* returns: nvarchar(128) */
```

Is that enough for what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly in SQL Server. This is most often accomplished in the application that is making the change. You might consider updating your application to be responsible for getting the client IP.